# Async calls within Dart Stream processing

Tags: dart, android-asynctask, nfc

I'm aware of similar questions, but, they don't quite do it. I want to get NTP time and access an URL whenever an NFC token is read. I'm modifying the example from nfc_in_flutter. So, I have this:

```
void _startScanning() {
        setState (() {
           _stream = NFC
              .readNDEF(alertMessage: "Custom message with readNDEF#alertMessage")
              .listen((NDEFMessage message) {
            if (message.isEmpty) {
              print("Read empty NDEF message");
              return;
            }
            print("Read NDEF message with ${message.records.length} records");
            for (NDEFRecord record in message.records) {
           //  String time_now = await get_time() ; 
           //  String my_ip = await get_url() ; 
    
              print(
                  "Record '${record.id ?? "[NO ID]"}' with TNF '${record.tnf}', type '${record.type}', payload '${record.payload}' and data '${record.data}' and language code '${record.languageCode}'");
            }
          }, onError: (error) {
```

The whole thing 'works' but:

```
       //  String time_now = await get_time() ; 
       //  String my_ip = await get_url() ;
```

Is not accepted by flutter, but works fine in the non-stream context. Is there some way of declaring async in this, or do I need to rebuild from scratch? I'm inexperienced with Dart/Flutter so would prefer to modify a working NFC example.

Comment: You are passing a non-async anonymous function to `listen`. Try `.listen((NDEFMessage message) async {`

Comment: Thanks @Riwen this produces an apk now, so looking good.